# What can I do about svmpath needing so much memory in one gulp?

Tags: r, svm

I am trying out the `svmpath` package, which is supposed to find optimal hyperparameters for a trained SVM without requiring multiple runs over different subsets of the data. More importantly, it's supposed to be less computationally complex (according to its [docs](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svmpath/index.html)).

However, it seems to ask for a lot of memory all at once.

Minimal working example:

```
library(data.table)
library(svmpath)
# Loaded svmpath 0.953

features <- data.table(matrix(runif(100000*16),ncol=16))
labels <- (runif(100000) > 0.7)
svmpath(x=features,y=labels)
# Error in x %*% t(y) : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
svmpath(x=as.matrix(features),y=labels)
# Error: cannot allocate vector of size 74.5 Gb

library(kernlab)
ksvm(as.matrix(features),y=labels,kernel=vanilla)
# runs
```

Inspecting the training function only shows one line that pops out as possibly big, `Kscript <- K * outer(y, y)`. Indeed this seems to be the culprit: `runif(100000) %o% runif(100000)` produces the same error.

Are there any quick fixes that are easy to implement in R?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it doesn't find the optimal C (cost) value.
But, it lists all the C values that you should try in order
to find the best one using N folds cross validation or a test dataset.